# How can I dump into the file raw packet using tcpdump utility?

Tags: python-3.x, tcpdump, raw-sockets, sniffer

I have the following code in python, that sniffs all packets from all interfaces:

```
import socket

def main():
    connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))

    while True:
        raw_data, addr = connection.recvfrom(65536)
        print(raw_data)

main()
```

Line "print(raw_data)" prints bytes string, here is the example of output:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00E\x00\x00(H\x1d@\x00@\x06\xf4\xb0\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x7f\x00\x00\x01\x1a\xc5\xa3\xdc\x00\x00\x00\x00g\\\x96\xa9P\x14\x00\x00\xf5&\x00\x00'
```

How can I get the same output with tcpdump or with other utility?